# falkon - unable to type or use keyboard shortcuts - Debian Bullseye

Tags: debian

I'm on Debian Bullseye XFCE.  Please find the relevant details of my system below:

```bsh
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ uname -a
Linux krishna 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-5 (2021-09-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ type -a falkon
falkon is /usr/bin/falkon
falkon is /bin/falkon
```

I installed `falkon` yesterday, checked some websites, changed some settings regarding privacy and appearance and restarted the browser. Since then, I am unable to type or use keyboard shortcuts. I have tested the keyboard in other applications. It works fine.

Then, I purged `falkon` including the directory `falkon` in `~/.config/falkon` and re-installed it. Everything is reset and fresh, but the same problem continues.

Could it be a problem with some Qt library files?

Please help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many `purge-install` cycles, everything works fine. My question is solved.